# db.SubmitChanges() not updating the database in Windows phone 8

Tags: database, windows-phone-8

my question might be similar to many question in google search but I have some specific query. I have written my code like this where db is database and Items is the table having filename as one property.

```
var query = from fs in dB.Items
              where fs.FilePath.Trim() == strOldpath.ToString()
              select fs;

                 foreach (var fs in query)
                 {
                    fs.FileName = txtrename.Text.ToString();                
                 }

                 try
                 {
                    dB.SubmitChanges();
                 }
                 catch (Exception e)
                 {

                 }
```

This code is running fine but after debugging  I stop the emulator and I run in the command prompt

`ISETool.exe ts xd 19xxxx-b6f2-474b-a747-6axxxxxxx E:\Practise\WinPhone\PhoneApp3\`

it creates the *.sdf in the specific folder and I can open that in server explorer. But I can see that instead of the updated fileName it shows the old File name. the code is running fine. Any help why the file name is not updated? I have set the primary key for the table also.

Comment: what if you read the data out, in code, on the device?

Comment: in device it is working fine, but for debug purpose we need to show to others. But the databse is not updating and display the old database, although submitChanges() works

Comment: you're either contradicting yourself or I really don't understand. How are you confirming that `SubmitChanges()` works if it doesn't update the database? For it to "work" surely it must update the database-that's what it does.

Comment: @MattLacey Sorry to say, but today I discovered that SubmitChanges is not working. It is not updating the Database. I checked the database it is still with the old value

Comment: What I come to know is that the db.SubmitChanges() is not working but not throwing any exception because     `ideaDB.ObjectTrackingEnabled = true` always. Even if I want to change it false it does not work. Saying `Data context options cannot be modified after results have been returned from a query.` So what I can guess is that the same database is being used somewhere internally. But in my application I am using it once at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have hit a known issue with trying to update the results of a read-only query:

[Workaround for LINQ to SQL Entity Identity Caching and Compiled Query Bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427624/workaround-for-linq-to-sql-entity-identity-caching-and-compiled-query-bug)

Comment: Thanks for your link, even that is also about the bug but is there any way I can do that? is there any solution?